# Compile ImageMagick Convert utility with image format support

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to compile ImageMagick convert utility on Ubuntu. But since I do not need the other utilities I am not using the configure file, rather compiling from the source files. The compilation works fine. And I can execute `convert -help` and `convert -version` commands. But when I try `convert -edge 0 logo.png logo_edge.png` it complains this

```
ImageMagickConvert: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `PNG' @ error/constitute.c//501.
ImageMagickConvert: NoImagesDefined `logo_edge.png' @ error/convert.c//3187.
```

Can you please help me answering any/both of the following two questions:

1. How can I add delegates without using configure file?
2. How can I install only convert utility using configure file?

Comment: If you install from binary, then Imagemagick comes with most needed delegates. If you install from source, then you must install all the delegates manually before installing Imagemagick. So you need to do  configure, make, make install for every one and for Imagemagick. I do not know if you can install only convert using source installs. Binaries, I believe, always come with all the tools. Note your syntax is wrong. Read the input just after convert and then do the processing commands. Then finally put the output.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. Cheers